# Coloring a bar based on its width

Tags: java, android, math

I have a special problem I am trying to solve.

Take a video game health bar, one that is fully green and slowly turns red until it is red when the bar's width is almost zero.

I am making an app that has a bar, and that bar's width can be anywhere from the full width of the screen to zero. Instead of having the bar change color based on its width from one color to another, I have **5** colors I am wanting it to change from.

At 100% I want the bar to be blue (#33B5E5).

At 80% I want the bar to be purple (#AA66CC).

At 60% I want the bar to be green (#99CC000.

At 40% I want the bar to be orange (#FFBB33).

And finally at 20% I want the bar to be red (#FFBB33).

I am leaving out 0% as anything below 20% will stay that same shade of red. NOTE: To ease confusion, I have the percentage of the bar, that is not the issue, the main goal is that while the width changes, it is a shade of the in-between colors.

Example: at 90%, the bar should be the color that is exactly between the blue and the purple, not either of them.

Mathematically, how would I go about doing this?

I am technically doing this in Java but any solution to this problem in any language, even pseudo-code, will be accepted.

EDIT: I am still getting answers that have the colors outputted given the interval. This is not what I am trying to accomplish. This is more of a mathematical problem. I am wanting the color to be *based on the percentage*. The only time the bar should ever be purple is when the percentage is *exactly* at 80%, at 70% the color should be exactly between purple and green. The point is so that the color is dynamic. The color changing all of the sudden to another static color simply isn't as visually interesting :)

Comment: in fact the pseudo-code is already contained in your question ;-)

Comment: my answer does in fact make a transition between the colors, so simply adding more color steps if needed would make the visuals you seek. A change for every 5% change in health I would think to be enough to be visually pleasant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a method reusing Android's LinearGradient, which supports non-even distribution of color stops. You would build the color array once upfront and use it as a lookup with the current percentage.

```
public static int[] getColors(int size) {

    LinearGradient gradient = new LinearGradient(0, 0, size, 1,
            new int[] {
                    0xffffbb33,
                    0xffffbb33,
                    0xff99cc00,
                    0xffaa66cc,
                    0xFF33b5e5 },
            new float[] {
                    0f, 0.2f, 0.4f, 0.6f, 1f },
            Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    p.setShader(gradient);

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, size, 1, p);

    int[] colors = new int[size];
    bitmap.getPixels(colors, 0, size, 0, 0, size, 1);
    bitmap.recycle();
    return colors;
}
```

Comment: How does this work in terms of percentages? What do I put in for the parameter of size? I am sure this works I am just trying to grasp how, thank you!!

Comment: If you pass a size of 101 you get back an int array of length 101, which you need for indexes ranging from 0 to 100 percent. So you could use colors[Math.round(percent)]. If you want finer nuances, e.g. a different color value for every half percent, you might double the size of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Just pieced this together, might need some work:

```
class HealthBar {

    public static final int ANIMATION_TIME = 500;

    String currentColor;
    View bar; // the view of the 

    public HealthBar(View view) {
        this.bar = view;
        this.currentColor = "#33B5E5";
    }

    public void updateHealthBar(int health) {

        if (health < 20) {
            tintColor("#FFBB33");
        } else if (health < 40) {
            tintColor("#FFBB33");
        } else if (health < 60) {
            tintColor("#99CC000");
        } else if (health < 80) {
            tintColor("#AA66CC");
        } else {
            tintColor("#33B5E5");
        }

    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi") private void tintColor(String newColor) {

        ColorDrawable[] color = {
                new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(currentColor)),
                new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(newColor)) };
        TransitionDrawable trans = new TransitionDrawable(color);
        int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            bar.setBackgroundDrawable(trans);
        } else {
            bar.setBackground(trans);
        }
        trans.startTransition(ANIMATION_TIME);

        this.currentColor = newColor;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to linearly lerp between the numbers.

For example:

```
int blue = Integer.parseInt("33B5E5", 16);
int purple = Integer.parseInt("AA66CC", 16);
int green = Integer.parseInt("99CC00", 16);
int orange = Integer.parseInt("FFBB33", 16);
int red = Integer.parseInt("FFBB33", 16);

int[] colors = new int[] {red, orange, green, purple, blue};

//Percent should be 0-100
public int getColorBasedOnPercent(int percent, int[] colors) {
    int intervalSize = 100 / (colors.length - 1);
    int startColor = Math.floor(percent / intervalSize);
    int endColor = Math.ceil(percent / intervalSize);

    float lerpAmount = (percent % intervalSize) / intervalSize;

    return (int)((colors[endColor] - colors[startColor]) * lerpAmount + colors[startColor]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative possible way is playing with Color.rgb:

```
    if (health < 20) {
        //default red here
    } else if (health < 40) {
        Color.rgb(256 - barLenghtPercent, 100, 100); // get something more red the shorter the bar
    } else if (health < 60) {
        // etc. same with other colors
```